# Can't solve 'infinite loop' with AzureSpatialAnchorsSample

Tags: hololens, azure-spatial-anchors

I downloaded the data from github and ran it. (github 'https://github.com/microsoft/OpenXR-Unity-MixedReality-Samples)

When I run it on HoloLens 2, it loads infinitely. When I run it in Unity, the following message is displayed in the debug window.

'There are 2 event systems in the scene. Please ensure there is always exactly one event system in the scene'

In Hierarchy, there is an event system existed in MixedRealityPlayspace > Main Camera and AR Session Origin > AR Camera.

When I cancel the Event System of the Main Camera,

'ARAnchorManager not enabled or available ; sample anchor functionality will not be enable. This application is not using the recommended Audio Spatializer Plugin. Go to Project Settings > Audio > Spatailizer Plugin and select one of the following : MS HRTF Spatializer, Microsoft Spatializer'

Import custom package Microsoft.SpatialAudio.Spatializer.Unity.1.0.18.unitypackage and

MixedRealityPlayspace > Main Camera > Event System unchecked, or Camera unchecked

If you uncheck AR Session Origin > AR Camera > Event System, or uncheck Camera, it is still

'There are 2 event systems in the scene. Please ensure there is always exactly one event system in the scene'
or
'ARAnchorManager not enabled or available; sample anchor functionality will not be enabled.'

A message similar to

Ask for help with these issues.

Answer (score 0):

Did the message "ARAnchorManager not enabled or available" disappear when you run on Hololens?
I suppose it happens only on PC because PC does not support AR Anchor

Answer (score 0):

T.LIM

I'm not sure if you have made any progress on this. If you have not, please file an issue [here](https://github.com/microsoft/OpenXR-Unity-MixedReality-Samples/issues) so the responsible engineer can take a look.